# What are these parts? -- "So she just stood there, ..., like in a trance, listening to ..., hoping that ..."

Tags: coordination, metaphors

> "So she just stood there, her head tilted to one side, **like in a trance**, **listening** to that wistful whispering, **hoping** that it would never end"

I wonder why V-ing (listening, hoping) are used here?

And "like in a trance"- I learned of "such as/ like" but I have never learned that it' used with a prepositional phrase. What is it?

Answer (score 3):

**like in a trance** simply means that it looked like she was in a trance (like one of those yogis), but in reality she wasn't.

pattern: *subject + predicate like something*

Example #1:

> He was chasing that car just **like in the movies**.

The whole situation of him chasing that car might have really looked like a movie, but that's of course not at all true because movies are movies and reality is reality.

Example #2:

> I've been waiting by that wall for two hours **like an idiot**, but she never came.

It doesn't make you an idiot per se, but just that when you wait for someone for a very long time and they don't show up you can say that you're an idiot because you're doing something that will yield fruitless results.

---

We have verbs ending in *ing* there because that's just how English grammar works.

pattern: *subject + predicate doing something*

Example #1:

> When I arrived at work early in the morning today, he was already there **going** through the mail we had received the day before.

When I came in to the office today early in the morning, I saw that he was already there and he was going through the mail.

Example #2:

> — Where's the dog, honey?
>   — He's outside **looking** for that bone we gave it yesterday.

The dog is outside and it is looking for the bone that the couple gave it yesterday.

---

PS: the subject of a sentence is the entity we are taking about. The predicate is what's being said about that entity. For example: *He is a good guy*. **he** is the subject. **is a good guy** is the predicate.

Answer (score 3):

Let me begin by saying that this sentence looks like someone speaking very informally, so the speaker may not have been very precise!

In this sentence, **listening** and **hoping** are present progressive verb forms.  You could interpret the sentence like this:
**She stood there.  Her head was tilted to one side.  She was listening to the wistful whispering.  She was hoping that it would never end.**
When we use them with a verb of action, movement, or position, they describe what the subject was doing at the same time.  For example, **She stood listening** = **She was standing** and **She was listening.**

"Like in a trance" is a very informal way of phrasing a *simile*.  The speaker is saying she appeared **as though she were in a trance**, or **in the manner of someone in a trance**.